Optimization problem for webcam to ASCII using 'rich' library in python
The code for this is in python and goes as follows
from PIL import Image
from rich.console import Console
from rich.text import Text
from cv2 import imwrite, VideoCapture
from os import system, name

# Function to map pixels to ASCII characters
def pixel_to_ascii(pixel, ascii_chars):
    return ascii_chars[pixel * len(ascii_chars) // 256]

# Function to convert image to colored ASCII
def image_to_ascii_with_color(image_path, new_width=100):
    ASCII_CHARS =  ["█"]

    # Open the image
    image = Image.open(image_path)

    # Resize the image maintaining the aspect ratio
    width, height = image.size
    aspect_ratio = height / width
    new_height = int(aspect_ratio * new_width * 0.4)
    image = image.resize((new_width, new_height))

    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gray_image = image.convert("L")

    # Get pixel data
    pixels = gray_image.getdata()
    color_pixels = image.getdata()

    # Create ASCII art
    ascii_str = "".join(pixel_to_ascii(p, ASCII_CHARS) for p in pixels)

    # Split ASCII string into lines
    lines = [ascii_str[i:i + new_width] for i in range(0, len(ascii_str), new_width)]

    # Print colored ASCII art using rich
    console = Console()
    for y, line in enumerate(lines):
        rich_text = Text()
        for x, char in enumerate(line):
            index = y * new_width + x
            if index < len(color_pixels):
                r, g, b = color_pixels[index]
                rich_text.append(char, style=f"rgb({r},{g},{b})")
        console.print(rich_text)

# Function to capture photo from webcam
def capture_photo(filename='1.jpg'):
    cap = VideoCapture(0)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Error: Could not open webcam.")
        return False

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cap.release()

    if not ret:
        print("Error: Could not read frame.")
        return False

    imwrite(filename, frame)
    return True

# Main function
def main():
    while True:
        if capture_photo():
            system('cls' if name == 'nt' else 'clear')
            image_to_ascii_with_color('image.jpg')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Whenever I run it it is very slow and sometimes starts to lag and make artifacts on the image making it look horrible. It will work fine at the start but the more it runs the more it lags and causes artifacts. The artifacts I'm talking about are miscolored pixels spreading through the canvas.
I have tried to use functools @cache and have not found a way to optimize it or get rid of the artifacts. I don't know if the problem can be fixed or if it is the rich library's fault but if someone could help that would be great. Also if someone could test for the artifacts in their terminal it would be appreciated. Please help me figure out this optimization and 'rich' library mystery. BTW I'm using vscode if anyone thinks that the problem.

I suggest you control the timing and skip frames if necessary because of a lag.
